# Not properly inserting simple Varchar? Generating string

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5, varchar, qcombobox

Running into an odd error and I just can't figure out what is going wrong. So I have a MySQL server I am running with a table setup using this script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Cases (
systemSN VARCHAR(15),
caseID int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT);
```

In Python 3.8.6, I am currently trying to implement a large form with some 19 fields into one table on a database, but I was running into problems so I have narrowed it down field by field, and this is the current basic INSERT I am unable to implement.

To generate the variable I am trying to insert into the MySQL database, I have users choose either line edits or comboboxes to select text strings, then I try, and have them upload those values into the table.

The combobox is displaying a list of strings like:

```py
systemSNs = ['----------------------', 'S129', '2342', 'a;sld']
for x in systemSNs:
    self.ncw_SystemSN_CB.addItem(x)
```

The function I use to pass the combobox value into the MySQL function is:

```py
def submitNewCase_call(self):
    print(self.ncw_SystemSN_CB.currentText())
    print(type(self.ncw_SystemSN_CB.currentText()))
    inputNewCaseintoDB(
        self.ncw_SystemSN_CB.currentText()
        )
```

And then I use this function to attempt to load the information into the database:

```
def inputNewCaseintoDB(systemSN):

    db = dbConnect()  #connects to my database
    mycursor = db.cursor()
    addCase = ("INSERT INTO Cases "
               "(systemSN) "
               "VALUES (%s)")
    mycursor.execute(addCase, systemSN)
    
    print(systemSN)
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

The Python error code I get in my pycharm terminal is:
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

If I substitute the variable `systemSN` for a `int`, I am able to do the insert fine, but for some reason I can't seem to input strings and I don't understand why not.

edit1:

Ex:

testFormMain.py

```py
from testForm import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys
import mysql.connector

def dbConnect():
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="password!",
        database="mysqldb"
    )
    return db

def inputNewCaseintoDB(systemSN):
    print(systemSN)
    db = dbConnect()
    mycursor = db.cursor()

    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO Cases "
                     "(systemSN)"
                     "VALUES (%s)",
                     (systemSN))
    db.commit()
    db.close()

class testFormMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,
                      Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.ncw_Submit_PB.clicked.connect(self.submitNewCase_call)

        systemSNs = ['----------------------', 'S129', '2342', 'a;sld']
        for x in systemSNs:
            self.ncw_SystemSN_CB.addItem(x)



    def submitNewCase_call(self):
        inputNewCaseintoDB(self.ncw_SystemSN_CB.currentText())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = testFormMain()
    widget.show()

    app.exec_()
```

testForm.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'testForm.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.1
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(393, 307)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.ncw_Submit_PB = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ncw_Submit_PB.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 210, 75, 23))
        self.ncw_Submit_PB.setObjectName("ncw_Submit_PB")
        self.ncw_SystemSN_CB = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ncw_SystemSN_CB.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 70, 231, 81))
        self.ncw_SystemSN_CB.setObjectName("ncw_SystemSN_CB")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 393, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.ncw_Submit_PB.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Submit"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

edit2:
An example of a function from elsewhere in my code that is trying to do a similar task (putting line edit fields into a database table) for James.  This one had no problems working as intended regardless of the characters I try to fill the VARCHAR with.

```py
def addCompany(companyName, businessPhone, faxPhone, streetAddress, city, state, zipCode, country):
    print(companyName, businessPhone, faxPhone, streetAddress, city, state, zipCode, country)
    db = dbConnect()
    mycursor = db.cursor()

    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO Company "
                     "(companyName,"
                     "businessPhone,"
                     "faxPhone,"
                     "streetAddress,"
                     "city,"
                     "state,"
                     "zipCode,"
                     "country)"
                     "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                     (companyName, businessPhone, faxPhone, streetAddress, city, state, zipCode, country))
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

Comment: 1) please provide a [mre] and 2) I recommend running your script from the console or CMD to get a more informative error message than a numerical code.

Comment: Added working code broken into UI part and the main code part.  Forgive me but I am a newer programmer and I don't understand how to effectively do such a script.

Comment: You have to open the terminal or CMD and run: `python /pàth/of/your/script`

Comment: @Gus you're using `mysql.connector`, where is `import mysql` in your code?

Comment: doesn't the string have to be sent to MySQL in double quotes? That would explain why `int` works -> `"VALUES (%s)",(systemSN))` --> `"VALUES (\"%s\")",(systemSN))` ... or some such?

Comment: @musicamante  You are correct, I left it out in this testcode on accident when trying to throw up generic pw/un's, but I did have it on my local test code and main code files.  Updated main file.

Comment: @James I dont know.  I use that syntax in other parts of my code effectively.  When I try to escape the quotes before %s my Pycharm starts throwing up errors.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you for that, I will use that more often to continue to find errors in my programming.  I get an error of ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

However this doesn't make sense to me.  Pycharm compiler is not complaining about mysql.connector not being imported, and I AM able to write to the database and see changes happen in other functions in this script, or if i change %s to just take in a 'string' or an int value directly instead of as a variable.

Comment: @Gus First of all, in order to ensure that your code is actually *reproducible* you should copy what *you are showing to us* in an external file and run it in a terminal. Then (and only *then*) if the exact error still is reproduced, you can update the question. You cannot rely too much on IDEs, as they have their own environment and behavior, which sometimes can differ from the actual behavior when the program is run in stand-alone mode.

Comment: @musicamante Sorry for the confusion, but that is what I have done at this point.  At the last minute before updating the code to Stack Overflow i realized I should show the dbConnect function and edited it prior to uploading.  I just goofed and forgot to also add the import.  This was a complicated code for me, and it took me a bit to find the best way to show the issue.

Comment: @eyllanesc Turns out I was getting the modulenotfounderror because I was running from console, and in the IDE I was using a virtual environment.  Had to reinstall my modules to get proper error messaging to diagnose what was really going on (1064 errors on the sql formatting)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the reason I was having so many problems is there is some non-intuitive formatting that happens when using python to insert single variables into a mysql database.

When I wrote the statement:

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO Cases (systemSN) VALUES (%s)", (systemSN))
```

I was getting 1064 errors that didn't like my formatting.  The problem is the variable name needed to be passed in a tuple.  The statement:

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO Cases (systemSN) VALUES (%s)", (systemSN,))
```

works fine.

I thought I was being smart trying to whiddle my insert down to a single variable at a time, but really I was just discovering a new problem!

Thanks for the tip on executing from console.  Much more useful error messaging!  Appreciate all the help.